# PYTHON DASH CORE COMPONENTS (DCC) download button is working on localhost but not on server (pythonanywhere)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, callback, plotly-dash

Python DCC download button is working on local host to download excel files but it's not working when I upload the code and try it on server (pythonanywhere). This code is part of my multi page Dash web application. DataFrame dt is defined 'global' as part of a function.
Here's the code:

> ***@callback(
> Output('download-comp','data'),
> Input('btn','n_clicks'),
> prevent_initial_call=True ) def func(n_clicks):
> return dcc.send_data_frame(dt.to_excel,'QUOTE VS ACT '+str(y)+'.xlsx',index=False)***

Comment: Look in your error and server logs for tracebacks that you can use to start debugging the problem.

Comment: need sufficient code to reporduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey @Anvesh , did you find any solution? I am also struggling to get this right on aws ec2.

Comment: @Harshal yes, this happened for me because I didn't have certain packages installed in the context of working environment on the server. I followed whast glen said. Check the error log to resolve